# How to change svg tags produced by gnuplot?

Tags: svg, gnuplot

I really like the gnuplot svg output, but is there any way to define the `<title></title>` and `<desc></desc>` tags that gnuplot generates?

The title defaults to `<title>Gnuplot</title>` and the description to `<desc>Produced by GNUPLOT 4.6 patchlevel 5</desc>` (or the version used, respectively).

**Is there any way to change these with gnuplot script code or is the only way to edit the output svg file?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's funny, I just had the SVG terminal driver up in my editor.  With GnuPlot 4.6.4 you can set the title with the terminal name option.  So when you set the terminal, also set the name option:

```
set term svg name "my title"
```

Note that the quotes around "my title" are important, otherwise you will get an unknown variable error.

From the terminal driver code, it looks like you can't change the description, it seems to be hard coded.

```
fprintf (gpoutfile, "<desc>Produced by GNUPLOT %s patchlevel %s </desc>\n\n",
         gnuplot_version, gnuplot_patchlevel);
```

Comment: Thanks. :) But `name` does not allow spaces even with quotation marks according to the error I just got when trying. It allows only alphanumerics and underscores.

Comment: @FooBar The `name` is also used as `id` of the `<g>` tag surrounding the plot, which is why you have this restriction.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't catch the spaces restriction.